# how to use shell script search directory pattern remotely

Tags: search, shell, design-patterns, scp

I need to use scp update some directory at another server. It is similar to

```
for i in /usr/some/???/unknown/dir
do
cp /usr/some/file $i
done
```

so how can i do the search while the destination directories are on other server?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in `ssh user@otherhost find /usr/some -type d -name dir`
do
  scp user@otherhost:/usr/some/dir/$i .
done
```

the find is what you're looking for I guess...

Answer (score 4):

Everybody forgets to handle spaces in file names :P

To reuse LB's example:

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$\'n'
for i in `ssh user@otherhost find /usr/some -type d -name dir`
do
  scp user@otherhost:"/usr/some/dir/$i" .
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

This will loop over each line of output instead of each word (and $i is quoted).

Comment: yep you're right... I always forget... but i always say spaces in file names are evil... :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `ssh user@otherhost ls /usr/some/dir/` 
do
 scp user@otherhost:/usr/some/dir/$i .
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access on the remote server, create a list of the directories remotely (using find, or ls, or whatever you'd use in your shell script), and copy it back to the system you're copying from.  Then you can use

```
for d in file_of_remote_dirs; do
    scp /usr/some/file remote_machine:d;
done
```